# Remove event in jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
    <div id="header">
        <h2>Jump for Joy Sale</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="guess-box"><img src="img/saina1.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="guess-box"><img src="img/saina1.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="guess-box"><img src="img/saina1.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="guess-box"><img src="img/saina1.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".guess-box").click(function() {
            $(".guess_box p").remove();
            var discount = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 5);
            var discount_msg = "<p>Your Discount is " + discount + "%</p>";
            $(this).append(discount_msg);
        }); //end click function
    }); //end doc ready
    </script>
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fn5jtk9/).

When an image is clicked it shows a random discount and it should hide it after clicking again, however it instead shows the discount again and again.
I tried using remove event, but it isn't working.

Comment: Your selector is wrong. `.guess_box p` should be `.guess-box p` (you probably want `$(this).find('p')` anyway)

Comment: `$(".guess_box p")` should have been `$(".guess-box p")`

Comment: thanks @billyonecan.. sorry for my simple mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are saying

```
$(this).append(discount_msg);
```

And this will always append the value at the end.

When you should be doing it like this

```
$(this).html(discount_msg);
```

This will remove any value there is and replace it with new one

**NOTE:** This will also delete the image. So you should specify the p tag as well in the selector

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong selector for targeting p elements. it should be `$(".guess-box p")` . :

```
$(".guess-box").click(function() {
  $(".guess-box p").remove();
  var discount = Math.floor((Math.random()*5) + 5);
  var discount_msg = "<p>Your Discount is "+ discount +"%</p>";
  $(this).append(discount_msg);
});
```

also you should only remove p elements from currently clicked and keep retain for others:

```
$(".guess-box").click(function() {
  $(this).find("p").remove();
  .......
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zwzg83wh/)**

Comment: Depends... if OP wants to remove all discounts or only in the current clicked `.guess_box`